# recharge the activity after back key

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activity
-scelta
-checkin
-instarghe

form scelta and checkin i can go to instarghe.
I want that when i go to instarghe from checkin,if I use the back button,the checkin activity will be re-excecute.
Example:
checkin-->instarghe-->back button-->I execute for the second time checkin 
scelta-->instarghe-->back button-->normally return to scelta
How can I do?

I write this code:

```
protected void onRestart(){
    //popolamento dello spinnero
    String risposta=postTarghe();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTarghe);
    final String targhe[]=risposta.split("/");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            targhe
            );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            sTarga=targhe[position];
            Log.d(TAG,"questa è la posizione selezionata: "+position);
            Log.d(TAG,"questa è la targa: "+sTarga);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
        }
    });
};
```

but when I try,the app crashs.
this is the logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.homelinux.agnese/com.homelinux.agnese.entrata}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.homelinux.agnese/com.homelinux.agnese.entrata} did not call through to super.onRestart()
>    Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.homelinux.agnese/com.homelinux.agnese.entrata} did not call through to super.onRestart()

Comment: "checkin activity will be re-excecute" can't perform only required work in onRestart and update the UI instead of creating checkin again?

Comment: is this fine ? or you have  some special requirement to  re-excecute checkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: please post your Code inside your Question, and not as an answer!

Second:

```
protected void onRestart(){
    /****************
    * You forgot following line
    ****************/
    super.onRestart();
    /***************/
    //popolamento dello spinnero
    String risposta=postTarghe();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTarghe);
    final String targhe[]=risposta.split("/");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            targhe
            );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            sTarga=targhe[position];
            Log.d(TAG,"questa è la posizione selezionata: "+position);
            Log.d(TAG,"questa è la targa: "+sTarga);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use `onRestart()` in checkin & use re-executing logic here. probably this will solve your problem.

call superclass `onRestart()` inside your overridden version of `onRestart()`